# Pythonic way to identify the origin of a unique numeric ID

Tags: python, performance

I am going to have a large dataset of unique numeric IDs, where each ID is equal to the sum of a subset of a list of values.

In one case, the values are all 10^x, where 1<=x<=23. So I have a list

```
list1 = []
for x in range(1,24):
    list1.append(10**x)
```

Which will contain a list of values ranging from 10 to 1e+23. My unique IDs are created in this manner:

```
idlist = [1,5,9,11]
uniqueID = 0
for x in idlist:
    uniqueID += list1[x-1]
```

This unique ID would be 101000100010, or 10^1 + 10^5 + 10^9 + 10^11. However, what I need to do is the reverse, where I have the ID and want the list of values ("idlist"). My current method (below) works, but I can't imagine it is the most effective way. I would greatly appreciate any recommendations on how to make this more efficient.

```
idlist = []
for x in reversed(range(1,24)):
    if uniqueID >= 10**x:
        uniqueID -= 10**x
        tmp.append(x)
```

"idlist" rightfully returns [1,5,9,11]

Comment: Your way seems fine to me, especially for x <= 23. Wrap it in a function, of course. (But… are these ids not actually binary?)

Comment: Curious: Why base 10?

Comment: This is just an example, not all IDs will be base 10. Probably not the best example to go with since I can see why that would create confusion, I just found it read the cleanest

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your IDs are numbers, not strings, so "be base 10" and "be binary" don't really make sense.

Comment: I edited to remove that part of the comment. None of the IDs are truly binary, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Okay, so how does it actually work? Because stringification with `str(n)` only works for decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```py
def id_list(unique_id):
    reversed = str(unique_id)[::-1]
    result = [
        i
        for i, num in enumerate(reversed)
        if num == "1"
    ]
    return result
```

Example: `id_list(101000100010)` results in:

```
[1, 5, 9, 12]
```

What the function does, in words, is to turn the ID into a string, reverses it, then checks each character to see if it's equal to `"1"`. If it is, the index of that character is added to a list. Then the list is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `log10` from the `math` module to accomplish this.  Taking the integer of `log10` gives you the largest power of 10 in the number.  Subtract that and repeat until the number is 0.  This gives you a list of the powers of 10 that compose the number.

Here I raise an exception if the number cannot be perfectly decomposed.

```py
from math import log10

def decompose_10(x):
    powers = []
    while x:
        p = int(log10(x))
        if p < 1:
            raise ValueError(f'{x} cannot be decomposed into sums of powers of 10')
        powers.insert(0, p)
        x = x - 10**p
    return powers

x = 101000100010

decompose_10(x)
# returns:
[1, 5, 9, 11]

decompose_10(x+3)
# raises:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-7c6a1e865b34> in <module>
----> 1 decompose_10(x+3)

<ipython-input-68-6310bad29158> in decompose_10(x)
      4         p = int(log10(x))
      5         if p < 1:
----> 6             raise ValueError(f'{x} cannot be decomposed into sums of powers of 10')
      7         powers.insert(0, p)
      8         x = x - 10**p

ValueError: 3 cannot be decomposed into sums of powers of 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider the following method which uses the modulo operator to find 1s. That said, for pure performance, you may want to shift your unique IDs from 10^N to 2^N since computers can do 2-based exponentiation and division much more quickly:

```
ids, x = [], 0
while uniqueId:
    n = unqiueId % 10
    uniqueId //= 10
    if n:
        ids.append(x)
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

a = 101000100010
idlist = [ x.start() for x in re.finditer('1', str(a)[::-1]) ]

print(idlist)
# Output: [1, 5, 9, 11]
```